# How to extend models in rails to always include a certain scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.1

In our multi-tenant, shared db application, I am looking for a way to extend models to always include the account scope as part of their SQL conditions when running a query. Ideally, i'd extend ActiveRecord so i can include something like `scoped_by_account` in all relevant models.

I've searched around the internet and found one plugin that claims to do just this. Unfortunately, the scoping searches part of the plugin is not working as far as I can tell. The plugin (which can be found here: https://github.com/mconnell/multi_tenant) extends ActiveRecord and uses the following code to 'inject' the additional search condition in every search:

```
def self.unscoped
    ...
    super.apply_finder_options(:conditions => { account_id => Account.current.id })
end
```

From what I can tell, this does not succeed in applying the condition to ***all*** searches. If I query `Project.all` it will return all results, ignoring the current account. Only if I use `Project.unscoped` it will work correctly.

**My question:**
How can I extend ActiveRecord to include my additional condition in every query it runs for that model?

Thx for your time,
Erwin

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for [default_scope](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#method-c-default_scope)?

Comment: no. In our app we use default_scope for various other things (such as setting default sort orders, etc). What I am looking for is to extend AR at a low lvl to insert a condition in **every** query it runs on that model.

Comment: Okay, but why not include that in the default scope for that model? Are you also asking if you join to this table that the condition is included?

Comment: Yes. The condition should always be included. The reason the default_scope will not work is because it can, and quite often has to be overridden. Then we have to worry about manually including the condition again. That is the reason we are looking for a low level, fail safe way of including it. We could override the basic AR finder method of course, but I was looking for a more elegant solution.